# How to set tabBarIcon from the state in navigationOptions (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to do something just like this. i have image in my state but its showing me undefined error.I am using tabNavigator from react-navigation.

```
static navigationOptions = {
   tabBarIcon:  <Image source={{uri: this.state.userImage}} style={{width:30, height: 30}}/>   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to define a function that returns your react native component, not the component itself.

```
static navigationOptions = {
   tabBarIcon: () => (<Image source={{uri: this.state.userImage}} style={{width:30, height: 30}}/>)
}
```

The error you're seeing is probably because you're trying to reference an instance of the component in a static method (`this.state.userImage`)